# How to add a keyword with a blank space in Listings package?

Tags: listings

I am trying to define a listing style in order to have fortran source codes which look like vim style colors.

For example, I would like to give a specific color to `end program` or `end module` or `double precision` ect ...

It is easy for keywords without blank character but I do not know how to do for keyword such as those above.

As you can see in the example below, the color of `program` is the good one but the color of  `end program` is not the good one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{keycolor}{RGB}{172, 42, 42}
\definecolor{vimvert}{RGB}{46, 139, 87}

\usepackage{listings}

% global parameters
\lstdefinestyle{global}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize\color{black!90},%
  stringstyle=\itshape\color{magenta},%
  showstringspaces=false,%
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{keycolor},%
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,%
}

% fortran style
\lstdefinestyle{fortranstyle}{
  language=Fortran,%
  style=global,%
  emph=[1]{implicit none, integer, real, double precision, character, len, parameter, structure, common},%
  emphstyle=[1]\bfseries\color{vimvert},%
  emph=[2]{program,end program, module, end module, subroutine, end subroutine, function, end function},%
  emphstyle=[2]\color{violet}\bfseries\slshape,%
  emph=[3]{call, true, false},%
  emphstyle=[3]\color{teal}\slshape%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=fortranstyle]
program calcPi

  implicit none

  integer            :: i, nbreDansCercle
  integer, parameter :: npts = 1000000000
  double precision   :: x, y, r, pi

  nbreDansCercle = 0
  do i = 1, npts, 1
      call random_number(x)
      call random_number(y)
      x = 2.d0 * x - 1.d0
      y = 2.d0 * y - 1.d0
      r = x**2 + y**2

      if (r < 1.d0) then
          nbreDansCercle = nbreDansCercle + 1
      end if
  end do

  pi = 4.d0 * dble(nbreDansCercle) / dble(npts)
  write(*,"('pi = ', F20.17)") pi

end program calcPi
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be the use of the `moredelim` key (see package manual section 3.3 "Delimters")

I defined two more delimeters:

- `moredelim=[is][emphstyle]{|>}{<|}` for `implicit none` and `double precision` that also don't get highlighted as you might want to define.
- `moredelim=[is][emphstyle2]{|<}{>|}` for `end program` and `end module`

There is one drawback: This has to be done manually or via Search-and-Replace and Regex but still, you can't simply copypaste code from your source or include it with `\lstinputlisting`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{keycolor}{RGB}{172, 42, 42}
\definecolor{vimvert}{RGB}{46, 139, 87}

\usepackage{listings}

% global parameters
\lstdefinestyle{global}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize\color{black!90},%
  stringstyle=\itshape\color{magenta},%
  showstringspaces=false,%
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{keycolor},%
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,%
}

% fortran style
\lstdefinestyle{fortranstyle}{
  language=Fortran,%
  style=global,%
  emph={[1]integer, real, character, len, parameter, structure, common},%
  emphstyle=[1]\bfseries\color{vimvert},%
  emph={[2]program, module, subroutine, function},%
  emphstyle=[2]\color{violet}\bfseries\slshape,%
  emph={[3]call, true, false},%
  emphstyle=[3]\color{teal}\slshape,%
  moredelim=[is][emphstyle]{|>}{<|},%
  moredelim=[is][emphstyle2]{|<}{>|}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=fortranstyle]
program calcPi

  |>implicit none<|

  integer            :: i, nbreDansCercle
  integer, parameter :: npts = 1000000000
  |>double precision<|   :: x, y, r, pi

  nbreDansCercle = 0
  do i = 1, npts, 1
  end do

  pi = 4.d0 * dble(nbreDansCercle) / dble(npts)
  write(*,"('pi = ', F20.17)") pi

|<end program>| calcPi
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output of code]

**PS:** You could also use `moredelim=[s][emphstyle]{implicit}{none}` (note the missing `i`) but this works only if you use `implicit` with a following `none`. The same applies to `double precision` and most importantly `end program`.
It would fail when it encounters an `end do` because `end` is still a delimiter which does not find a `program` and it will all be set in `emphstyle`.

Comment: I think that your last solution in the post scriptum is the best one and the simplest one ! Thanks

Comment: Actually, `moredelim=[s][emphstyle]{implicit}{none}` does not work. If I did that, all the text after `implicit none` is green.