# Highlighting keywords with spaces with the listings package

Tags: listings, highlighting, keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to emphasize within a listing two successive identifiers separated by a space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/how-to-emphasize-within-a-listing-two-successive-identifiers-separated-by-a-spac)

I am trying to highlight the following keywords with the **listings** package:

> over window:time
>
> over window:length

If I declare:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{drl}{
  morekeywords=[2]{length,over,time,window},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{darkred}\bfseries
}
```

I get the job done, however the colon is not highlighted and I cannot use *length*, *over*, *time* and *window* as identifiers or otherwise they are highlighted as keywords (*time*, for example, is often used as identifier in my language since I have to deal with temporal events and operators).

So I tried the following:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{drl}{
  alsoletter={:},
  morekeywords=[2]{over,window:length,window:time},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{darkred}\bfseries
}
```

and now *window:length* and *window:time* are properly recognised as a single entity but still I cannot user *over* as an identifier. So I tried to go further on that way by declaring the following (comments represent additional unsuccessful tries):

```
\lstdefinelanguage{drl}{
  alsoletter={ ,:},
  % alsoletter={\ ,:},
  % alsoletter={{ },:},
  morekeywords=[2]{over window:length,over window:time},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{darkred}\bfseries
}
```

How are blankspaces encoded? What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated! 
Below you can find a full working example if you want to play with the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{151,0,11}

\lstdefinelanguage{drl}{
  alsoletter={ ,:},
  % alsoletter={\ ,:},
  % alsoletter={{ },:},
  morekeywords=[2]{over window:length,over window:time},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{darkred}\bfseries
}

\lstset{
  gobble=4,
  language=drl
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    over = 5 s;
    time = 10 ms;
    eval(time < over)
    this over window:length( 5 )
    this over window:time( 30s )
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This appears to be impossible, at least without altering your code.  See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/how-to-emphasize-within-a-listing-two-successive-identifiers-separated-by-a-spac) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72917/how-to-add-a-keyword-with-a-blank-space-in-listings-package).

Comment: Thanks!
I wonder how I missed those posts...
Anyway now I know at least the direction to go!