# Listings - two word keywords

Tags: listings

I use the OPL language for optimization and I’m writing some notes on Latex using "listings". I defined the language and the keywords, so far no problems. However I have a keyword “subject to” and a keyword “to SheetWrite” that I need to be colored differently. The problem is the word “to” that appears in both keywords. Is there a way to define two word keywords in listings or otherwise solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself with our format. Regarding to your question, I guess one of these links will answer your question: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185131/keywords-with-spaces-in-listings), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72917/how-to-add-a-keyword-with-a-blank-space-in-listings-package), [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/how-to-emphasize-within-a-listing-two-successive-identifiers-separated-by-a-spac). But I'm not sure if it's a duplicate...