# LaTeX listing of command line syntax

Tags: listings

I have a LaTeX document using the listings package for some bash scripts. I'd like to create a different styling for text that is meant to show the syntax of a command. For instance, I have the following command in a bash-styles listing:

```
java -jar /usr/share/java/picard/MarkDuplicates.jar INPUT=<alignment_file.bam> \
  VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=LENIENT OUTPUT=alignment_file.dup \
  METRICS_FILE=alignment_file.matric ASSUME_SORTED=true REMOVE_DUPLICATES=true
```

However, I'd like to style this differently to a command that is actually entered into a terminal, since it is not a real command but just showing the syntax to be used. Is there a default styling for such a thing. Perhaps following:

Note the following conventions in the definition of the command parameters:

```
Angle brackets ( < > ) indicate a mandatory parameter.
Square brackets ( [ ] ) indicate an optional parameter. If you omit the parameter, InfoSphere CDC uses a default value.
A vertical bar ( | ) separating one or more parameters indicate that only one of the parameters in the list can be used. When one or more vertical bars appear in a list of parameters that is enclosed by square brackets [ ], the choices are limited to the parameters in the list, but you have the option to not specify any of the parameters.
Ellipsis ( ... ) means that a parameter or option can be repeated more than once.
Unless otherwise noted, the commands apply to all operating systems.
```

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution. Some comments are appropriate:

- The options in the scope of the `|` have to be delimited some way, in this example I have used the colon `:` as a delimiter. It does not show on the output because the option `[is]` in the definition (`i` stands for invisible).
- I'm not sure that the ellipsis works as you are expecting (currently it is just highlighted in magenta).

If you want to combine this kind of hihglighting with the `bash` highlighting already provided by `lstlistings`, I have added some code as an example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{args}{
sensitive=false,
alsoletter={.},
moredelim=[s][\color{red}]{<}{>},
moredelim=[s][\color{blue}]{[}{]},
moredelim=[is][\color{orange}]{:}{:},
keywords=[10]{...},
keywordstyle=[10]{\color{magenta}},
}

\lstnewenvironment{arguments}
{\lstset{language=args}}
{}

\lstnewenvironment{bash}
{\lstset{numbers=left,language=bash,keywordstyle={\color{blue}}}}
{}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily\small

\begin{arguments}
program <mandatory arg> [optional arg]  :a | b: out ... .. .
\end{arguments}

\begin{bash}
echo 'hello world'
\end{bash}

\end{document}
```