# Spacing between words in listings package and emphasizing identifiers

Tags: spacing, listings, emphasis

I have written some source code using `listings` package but is stretching out of the page. This package leaves huge spaces between the words, so is there a way to make them smaller? At least like the spaces in normal text?

Also I tried to use `emph` and `emphstyle` and it only identifies single words. I wrote `for each` and it doesn't recognize it. What should I do to recognize multiple words?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage
[
  top=0.7in,
  bottom=1.2in,
  left=0.8in,
  right=0.8in
]{geometry}


\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}


\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}


%Math fonts

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lstset
{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    emph=
    {
    if, for each, loop do,
    then return, function
    },
    emphstyle=\color{red}
}

\selectlanguage{english}


\begin{lstlisting}[title={Breadth-First Search}]
function BREADTH-FIRST-SEARCH(Problem) return A solution or failure

Node= Root

if Problem.GOAL-TEST(Node.STATE) then return SOLUTION(Node)

Frontier= Node

Explored= Empty

loop do

    if EMPTY(Frontier) then return failure

    Node= POP(Frontier)

    add Node.STATE to Explored

    for each Action in Problem.ACTIONS(Node.STATE) do

        Child= CHILD-NODE(Problem,Node,Action)

        if Child.STATE is not in Explored or Frontier then

            if Problem.GOAL-TEST(Child.STATE) then return SOLUTION(Child)
            Frontier=INSERT(Child, Frontier)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Ok I will edit now!

Comment: You seem to be asking two unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Comment: @Jubobs I thought that because the problems appeared together and there were both regarding `listings` it would be better not to keep asking about the same package. If there is a problem I can of course separate them.

Comment: Add also `columns=flexible` to `\lstset`.

Comment: @egreg thank you I added it and it kind of helped but it is still a pretty big gap.

Comment: @Adam I can't see big gaps: the space between words is the same width as the letters.

Comment: @egreg this is a little subjective but I copied some code from a text book and the one from `listings` stretches far more that the one in the book. And this with a monospace font! It seems logical to me that there must be a parameter in listings to change that, as it is importand in source code to keep some context in the same line.

Comment: @Adam About your first question, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/how-to-emphasize-within-a-listing-two-successive-identifiers-separated-by-a-spac?rq=1. About your second question: you may have tab characters in your listings. They have a width of 8 spaces by default. That may be why your listing appears too wide.

Comment: @Jubobs thank you. I have set the tabs in spacific number of spaces but I will check it again. :)